# Issue about pl2303 on Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: drivers, usb

When i send data via /dev/ttyUSB0 which is created by the driver pl2303 , it is always sending the data that is last time i wondering send. That meaning : if i type the command as below:

```
echo hello > /dev/ttyUSB0 ## the receiver can`t get any infomation
echo 1 > /dev/ttyUSB0 ## the receiver get "hello"
echo 123 > /dev/ttyUSB0 ## the receiver get "1"
```

that is quite odd issue...i have no idea to fix it.

BTW: my linux kernel version is 2.6.24-26-generic(Ubuntu 8.04)

Comment: No longer supported

Answer (score 2):

Try appending either "\n" or "\r" to each echo statement.

i.e.

```
echo "hello\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

or

```
echo "hello\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

or even

```
echo "hello\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```